# How to fix. 'ion-toggle set on value from db'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwMcm.png)Hello i want the toggle button to be set according to the value that it gets from database. I have return the object that not an issue. I just want to get it to a value. Of course the toggle could be change and send another value to db with ngModel

I done it with disabled but thats for disabling the toggle.

In the image you see two toggles that are off. I want the one to be on if the details.status value is 1 and not 0

```
 <ion-toggle [disabled]="!isValidStatus()" [(ngModel)]="mediaData.status"></ion-toggle>
 isValidStatus()
    {
        if(this.details.status == '0')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(this.details.status == '1')
        {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by toggle to check or not

```
 <ion-toggle [checked]="details.status" [(ngModel)]="details.status"></ion-toggle>
```

or

```
 <ion-toggle [checked]="mediaData.status" [(ngModel)]="mediaData.status"></ion-toggle>
```

Comment: no, i want it to be shown, just according to value from db to be on or off

Comment: you mean checked (true) not checked (off) ?

Comment: why you added a function to return a true or false ?

Comment: yes checked if object has value 1  not checked if object has value 0. Didnrt know how to do it.

Comment: should it get the values after response? how is it going to set them? with ngModel? I mean how am i going to give it the values. I just nav param the parameters from the previous page.

Comment: if you can provide us the error or a screenshot after trying this " <ion-toggle [checked]="this.details.status" [(ngModel)]="mediaData.status"></ion-toggle>
"

Comment: how is the toggle going to get the value if you are not setting it in the component or with the function?

Comment: when you add the brackets to a tag it will follow the value of the variable between double quote "" "details.status" in your case so you don't need a function to return a value because the value exist in the variable

Comment: i did <ion-toggle [checked]="{{details.status}}" and i am getting a Template parse error Got interpolation ({{}})

Comment: Try this : I used in an old code and it works for me [checked]="details.status === true"

Comment: well this is working for me : 

 <ion-toggle [checked]="details.status" [(ngModel)]="details.status" (ionChange)="test()"></ion-toggle>

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-du1r1o?file=app%2Fapp.html

Comment: Maybe is because you didn't linked it to a db to get results. Anyway i ll find the answer and post it here